# Delete method of Range class failed, when using any variation of "EntireRow.Delete"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through all the cells in a specified column of a used range and delete any rows where the value equals that of another value specified in a variable.  However, anytime I try and use some variation of .EntireRow.Delete I get an error message:

Run-Time Error '1004':
Delete method of Range class failed

I remember this working back in the day (Excel 2007) so I'm a little confused why it wouldn't work anymore.  Did MS depreciate it?  It seems like such a useful little piece of code so I can't see why they would.

Anyways, here's the code below, if anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

```
Dim rngColumnRef As String
    rngColumnRef = "$A:$A"
Dim rngDeleteValue As String
    rngDeleteValue = "X"
    Set tempRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(rngColumnRef)
    For i = 1 To tempRange.Rows.Count
        If ActiveCell.Value = rngDeleteValue Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete 'this is where I get the error
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: There is no code to **Set** ActiveCell before entering the loop.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - The `ActiveCell` is whatever cell is currently selected in the Worksheet.  I don't have to set it.  To confirm, I ran the     `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select` and had no problems selecting the entire row.  The issue is with the Delete method failing.

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: @Lowpar - No, it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I had a Table (or `ListObject`) in the sheet that wasn't converted to a range.  Since the Table was part of the row I was trying to delete, it simply wouldn't let me do it.  Here's the modified code (or additional code) I used to correct this:

```
'New Code

   Dim TableRange as ListObject 'Ideally I would place all my declarations 
                             'up here, but I wanted to show a very
                             'clear, Before and After picture of the code.

   For Each TableRange in ActiveSheet.ListObjects    
       TableRange.Unlist
   Next TableRange

'End of New Code    

Dim rngColumnRef As String
    rngColumnRef = "$A:$A"
Dim rngDeleteValue As String
    rngDeleteValue = "X"
    Set tempRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(rngColumnRef)
    For i = 1 To tempRange.Rows.Count
        If ActiveCell.Value = rngDeleteValue Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete 'this is where I got the error
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rngColumnRef As String
    rngColumnRef = "$A:$A"
Dim rngDeleteValue As String
    rngDeleteValue = "X"
    Set tempRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(rngColumnRef)
    For i = 1 To tempRange.Rows.Count
        If ActiveCell.Value = rngDeleteValue Then
            rows(i).EntireRow.Delete 'this is where I get the error
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: I'll check this out.

Comment: Well, it didn't work but I found out something else.  I didn't include this on my original question because I didn't think it made a difference but I see now that it might.  This worksheet that I'm trying to delete rows from is a direct Copy...of another workbook sheet.  In otherwords `Sheets("Sheet1").Copy`.  I'm then trying to modify that "Copy".  When I try and delete rows from that "Copy" it's throwing that error.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies Lowpar but it looks like I had a Table in the sheet I was trying to modify which was causing the issue.  I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with the Macro Security. For me it worked when I selected "Enable all Macros"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in my case both commands below were failing, what caused me to consider it is not the code but the file corrupted.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Insert

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Delete
```

Try both lines individually. If both fail the problem is probably because your file is corrupted (you probably tried to do some operation beyond the maximum line or maximum column of worksheet and file is not ok anymnore).

Solutions is to create a new file and transfer all data, formulas and VBA code to this new file.